# How to create a folder of current date and time And copy some other folder in that recently made folder in python

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system, filesystems, file-handling, sys

I have tried it in Jetbrains Pycharm but it is showing an error.

Here is my code

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
import shutil
now = datetime.now()
dt=now.strftime("%d%m%Y %H%M%S")
os.mkdir(dt)
shutil.copytree(r"C:\Users\Computer\PycharmProjects\06\08",r"C:\Users\Computer\PycharmProjects\Filecopy\dt")
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Also you should consider this format for the directory name -- "%m%d%Y_%H%M%S"

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use the path of your newly-created directory, the line should do:

```py
..., r"C:\Users\Computer\PycharmProjects\Filecopy\{}".format(dt))
```